# Dumb question - does normal map override face normals?

Tags: mesh, texturing, shaders

It seems to be a stupid question but I can't find answer. If I use a normal map on a 3D object, does normal map override face normals or there is a blending of the normals from both sources?

I ask for it because I need to use some reinforcement loop to maintain normal on mesh when I use image maps.

Sorry for my approximate english.

Answer (score 3):

The face normals remain the same. Only during rendering every pixel and/or light ray takes normal map into account as a variation relatively to the "standard" face normal.

Comment: OK so it is a mix from both face and normal map. Thank you !