# Specular reflection displays original faces of my model despite defining an object space normal map

Tags: normals, normal-map

In my scene, I have a Suzanne where I'm attempting to paint normal maps in Object Space (as it's easier to create facets). However, when I preview it, it's apparent that the normal map doesn't entirely override the original normals of the model.
[image]

[image]
I'm not quite certain about the source of the issue, whether it's a rendering limitation or an unfamiliar setting on my end.

I've also come across this question:
["https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/240217/dumb-question-does-normal-map-override-face-normals"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/240217/dumb-question-does-normal-map-override-face-normals).
Perhaps this could be the reason behind the issue, but I'm unsure about how to fix it.

Here is my blend file with textures packed :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1djuOiwWOkW8P8TpSLGzB_5t5fHji_rfq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is an interesting problem, where I think it's a bug.  The problem isn't the normal map (evidence: can still see the faces when setting normal via Combine XYZ node instead) but something being done in Blender's glossy component (and maybe elsewhere as well.)  I'm still investigating, trying to figure out in which version this became a problem-- 2.80, it works.

Comment: After more investigation, I made a bug report at https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/111805 .